# Swift: import ObjectiveC vs Foundation

Tags: swift, import, foundation

What is the difference between `import ObjectiveC` & `import Foundation` in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

Foundation is more inclusive than ObjectiveC. I'm not sure, however, if Foundation is a superset (if you will) of ObjectiveC. I.e., ObjectiveC might include things not included by Foundation.

Anyway, if, e.g., you're just subclassing from `NSObject`, you can just `import ObjectiveC.NSObject` instead of `import Foundation.NSObject`, which also works but includes more than needed.

If, however, e.g., you're declaring a property of type `NSDate`, `import ObjectiveC.NSDate` doesn't work, so you'll have to `import Foundation.NSDate`.

Comment: Correct And

If you want access other user-define class method or parameter then you have to user bridging header to include 

customClass
like

import CustomClass.h